# Preventing the page number from appearing on the title page of part

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, parts

Can someone help me to get rid of the page number at the bottom of the `\part` title page in the `book` document class?

Using

```
\renewcommand{\part}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

will change the font and style of the part's title page altogether.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this would be to copy the contents of the `empty` page style into the `plain` page style momentarily:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
\part{foo}
\endgroup

\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}​
```

You could also use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to modify (or patch) the `\part` command to *not* use the `plain` page style:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}% Use empty page style, not plain
```

<sub>The last two arguments of `\patchcmd` can be used to output something based on a successful patch (second-to-last argument) or not (last argument): `\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}`</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The `\part` command is defined in `book.cls` with the `plain` style. You can modify this to `empty` by inserting the following code in your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
```